# check whether the image exists or not in downloads android

Tags: android, download, android-download-manager

I want to check whether the image is already exists in Download folder in Android.In there  if section is not working. If file is already there (Ex: image name - hair_61), when downloading the same image for the second time it's downloading the file as hair_61-1. I have tried the code below. I want to show a message if the file is already there and restrict from downloading further how am I suppose to do?.

Appconstants.java:

```
public class AppConstants {

//storage
public static final String MEDIA_FOLDER = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ File.separator + "PubImg";
public static final String DOWNLOADS_FOLDER = MEDIA_FOLDER + File.separator + "Downloads/";
}
```

download function:

```
downloadimage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(
                    Uri.parse(imgUrl));
            request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.
                    Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);

            FileUtils.createDirectory(AppConstants.DOWNLOADS_FOLDER);
            File imageFile = new File(AppConstants.DOWNLOADS_FOLDER + "hair_" + photoID + ".jpg");
            if(imageFile.exists()) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image is Already downloaded",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else {
                request.setDestinationUri(Uri.fromFile(imageFile));

                DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                dm.enqueue(request);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Downloading File",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
        });
```

Comment: File file = new File ( ...path to file... ); if (file.exists()) Toast( ...file exists...);

Comment: Please dont post code for a download manager if the only thing you wanna ask is how to check if a file exists. Once you have checked that the file not exists you can start a download manager. Dont build up a request before that. But that is another story.

Comment: how can I stop that image getting downloaded again?

Comment: Dont start the download manager if the file already exists.

Comment: File file = new File ( ...path to file... ); if (file.exists()) Toast( ...file exists...) doesn't worked

Comment: If you used it as i wrote it down then of course it will not compile. Please telll which path you used.

Comment: see above I have include it in my code

Comment: I do not see a file.exists(). And again: Check if the file exists before you mess around with a download manager. You should do that in the first lines of onClick().

Comment: yeah it worked thanks...I have put download manager at a wrong place

Comment: Blackapp can you help me out for this post (following is my post)"https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59107104/how-to-make-viewpager-and-gridview-scroll-vertical-at-a-same-time"