# how to make ViewPager and gridview scroll vertical at a same time

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-viewpager, scrollview

I have ViewPager and grid view in my activity.i want when I scroll anywhere on screen both ViewPager and grid view should scroll at a same time.here is my ss :[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLExG.jpg).now the only few images are displayed in grid view I have 63 images but shows only 9 in grid..2)[ss main](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xu8th.png)

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#fff">
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"/>


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/SliderDots"
    android:layout_below="@+id/viewPager"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="15dp"/>


<GridView
    android:id="@+id/mGridView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="554dp"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:columnWidth="172dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
    />
</LinearLayout>
 </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: don't you want your GridView inside the ViewPager ? Instead of under

Comment: no I want them separately...and scroll vertical both at a same time..look at screenshot link I have added

Comment: hey I edited my code ..now only few images in grid displayed but scroll worked...but I want images to display

Comment: BUT I want all images to displayed in grid

Comment: then why do you use a ViewPager ?

Comment: because it is one of my requirements in my project..see ss above second one

Answer (score 2):

**Use this code to resolve your problem**

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">


<LinearLayout
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical">

<androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
android:id="@+id/viewPager"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="150dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"/>


<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/SliderDots"
android:layout_below="@+id/viewPager"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="15dp"/>


<GridView
android:id="@+id/mGridView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ffffff"
android:columnWidth="172dp"
android:gravity="center"
android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
android:numColumns="auto_fit"
android:paddingLeft="5dp"
android:paddingTop="5dp"
android:paddingRight="5dp"
android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
android:verticalSpacing="5dp" />

</LinearLayout>

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: nope doesnt work ...now grid view starting two image is only getting displayed

Comment: android:fastScrollEnabled="true"

in nested scroll view

Comment: under nested scrollview?

Comment: hello if grid view not work you can use recyclerview grid view it working proper

Comment: recyclegridview?I thought grid view itself is a recycling views as it is using adapter...

Comment: hey I edited my code ..now only few images in grid displayed but scroll worked...but I want images to display

Answer (score 1):

You must be use **CUSTOM** **viewpager** to achieve vertical scrolling of viewpager because **default viewpager** doesn't support vertical scrolling with other components.

Check my below code.

```
public class CustomViewPager extends ViewPager {

    private View mCurrentView;

    public CustomViewPager(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        if (mCurrentView == null) {
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
            return;
        }
        int height = 0;
        mCurrentView.measure(widthMeasureSpec, MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
        int h = mCurrentView.getMeasuredHeight();
        if (h > height) height = h;
        heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);

        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }

    public void measureCurrentView(View currentView) {
        mCurrentView = currentView;
        requestLayout();
    }

    public int measureFragment(View view) {
        if (view == null)
            return 0;

        view.measure(0, 0);
        return view.getMeasuredHeight();
    }
}
```

Apply this **Class** instead of **default ViewPager** into your fragment. THAT'S IT!!